# How to calc coordinates of a middle of calculated segment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (a) at (-2,5);
  \coordinate (b) at (-2,0);
  \coordinate (c) at (2,0);
  \coordinate (d) at (2,5);

  \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d);

  \draw[fill=gray] ([yshift=-0.5cm]$(a)!0.3!(b)$) rectangle ($(d)!0.3!(c)$);
  
  \draw[->] ([yshift=-0.2cm]$(a)!0.3!(b) + (a)!0.5!(d)$) -- ++(0,-2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to draw a vector from a middle of gray rectangle. But my calculations are wrong. How can I do that without defining special coordinates for (a)!0.3!(b) and (d)!0.3!(c) and then calc the middle between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pos=0.5` or `midway` also works for rectangles.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (a) at (-2,5);
  \coordinate (b) at (-2,0);
  \coordinate (c) at (2,0);
  \coordinate (d) at (2,5);

  \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d);

  \draw[fill=gray] ([yshift=-0.5cm]$(a)!0.3!(b)$) rectangle
  coordinate[pos=0.5] (M)  ($(d)!0.3!(c)$);
  
  \draw[<-] (M) -- ++ (0,2);
  %\draw[->] ([yshift=-0.2cm]$(a)!0.3!(b) + (a)!0.5!(d)$) -- ++(0,-2);
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: interesting, thanks! Nonetheless, I'd like to know if it's realizable in $calc$ mode (for future cases)

Comment: @Allok Sure, `\draw[<-] ($([yshift=-0.5cm]$(a)!0.3!(b)$)!0.5!($(d)!0.3!(c)$)$) -- ++ (0,2);` also works, i.e. you can nest the `calc` syntax, and `!0.5!` between two coordinates gives you the one in the middle.

Comment: I thought such intuitive composition wouldn't work and haven't even tried it) thanks!